# How to reduce duplication in Rails RSS reader sync.rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've been working through a Ruby on Rails RSS reader with a PostgreSQL database. At the moment, it syncs with the existing feeds properly, but it seems to reiterate over Articles it already has in the database. I would like to only iterate over Articles that I don't yet have in the database. Can anyone help me figure out how to properly do that with my sync.rake task, pictured below? Thanks!

```
namespace :sync do
    task feeds: [:environment] do
        Feed.all.each do |feed|
           content = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse feed.url
           content.entries.each do |entry|
               local_entry = feed.articles.where(title: entry.title).first_or_initialize
               text = Nokogiri::HTML(open(entry.url))
               local_entry.update_attributes(content: text, author: entry.author, url: entry.url, published: entry.published)
               p "Synced Entry - #{entry.title}"
           end
           p "Synced Feed - #{feed.name}"
       end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use `published` field to find the most recent publication, that is stored in your database.

So you can run something like:

```
last_entry = feed.articles.last
content.entries.reject { |e| e.published < last_entry.published }
```

And after that to iterate over filtered collection to create new entries.